# Textbox, checkbox and isset freeze

Tags: php, checkbox

I'm trying to create php script and form using _POST(isset), where if a checkbox is checked, then it shows additional info.

```
if (isset($_POST['child-lists'])) {

  show 'child list' called by stored procedure

} else {

show 'parent list' called by stored procedure.

}
```

What I want is when 'child lists' is checked, it prints/shows both 'parent list' AND 'child lists'. When unchecked it only shows 'parent list' With if..else, it does one of the other.

However, if I remove the else command, my program freezes or infinite loops. I'm still noobish with server side programming, so I know I'm missing something rudimentary.

How can I have the script show additional items when a checkbox is checked without freezing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post the rest of your code. There are no loops as far as the eye can see here.

Comment: Removing an else from that would NOT cause a freeze by itself. But since you don't show the rest of the code around that if() statement, we can't help you.